# pythonanywhere django не собираются статические файлы из приложения

Tags: python, django, static, pythonanywhere

Проблема заключается в том, что на pythonanywhere не собираются статические файлы из приложения Django.
После команды

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

В директории

```
/home/user/user.pythonanywhere.com/static
```

Появляется только папка admin.
Настройки settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp'
]
```

Расположение css файла:

```
+---myapp
|   +---static
|   |   \---myapp
|   |       \---css
|   |           \---myapp.css
```

При выполнении комманды python manage.py collectstatic в локальной коммандной строке, статический файлы из приложения собираются, проблема именно в pythonanywhere.

Все действия стандартные, выполнял всё строго по гайду, не могу понять в чем дело. Спасибо

Я прочитал все статьи на эту тему на pythonanywhere и всё что нашел на stackoverflow и в документации, но ничего не помогает решить проблему.

```
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles/
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles
```

Comment: а создается ли папка static в корне проекта django?

Comment: Да, папка static создается и имеет путь /home/user/user.pythonanywhere.com/static. В данной папке создается папка admin, тогда как на моём локальном сервере создается также папка myapp/css/ с нужным мне CSS файлом. Параметр BASE_DIR = Path(file).resolve().parent.parent

Comment: добавьте STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapps/static'),] или project/static

Comment: @JopaBoga в таком случае я получаю ошибку:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'/home/user/user.pythonanywhere.com/blog/static'
Мне кажется основная проблема в том, что я добавил /static в .gitignore файл? Поэтому pythonanywhere bash console не видит static файлы? Потому что они не были загружены на гитхаб? Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить процесс загрузки static файлов? Я прочитал эти статьи документации, но всё равно не могу разобраться:
docs/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/
docs/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: путь должен быть '/home/user/user.pythonanywhere.com/static', а не ваше apps, то есть путь в проект. попробуйте